# How can I wrap a <span> around the first character in an object with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been able to find and console.log the first characters that meet my criteria. I am trying to wrap a `<span>` tag around the characters but keep running into trouble. This is what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.drop-cap').each(function(i,obj) {
  $(this).find("p").text().charAt(0).append("<span class='dropcap'>");
 })
});
```

Comment: [You're close](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Do you really need JavaScript? `p:first-child:first-letter { ... }` https://jsfiddle.net/fmt98z23/

Comment: @epascarello Sorry to follow up late on this. But this CSS worked perfectly for my use case. Thank you. I had no idea I could target child objects, let alone the first letter in CSS.

Comment: @JonP Thank you as well for pointing out the .wrap() function. That will be very useful

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the `substring` function to get part of a string which will allow you to separate the start from the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drop-cap').each(function(i,obj) {
        var $p   = $(this).find("p"),
            text = $p.text();
        
        if(text.length === 0){
            // no text to be wrapped
            return;
        }

        $p.html('<span class="dropcap">' + text[0] + '</span>' + text.substring(1));
    })
});
```

**ES6**

```
$(document)
  .ready(() => {
      $('.drop-cap')
        .each((index, element) => {
            let $p   = $(element).find("p"),
                text = $p.text();
        
            if(text.length === 0){
                // no text to be wrapped
                return;
            }

            $p.html(`<span class="dropcap">${text[0]}</span>${text.substring(1)}`);
        });
  });
```

Comment: I made an edit to check if the string is empty otherwise it would include `undefined` in the final text

Comment: Apologies for following up late. But this worked out perfectly for my needs as well, ultimately the CSS above does this trick, but this is exactly what I was trying to do.Thank you.